# Can't create tables inside Visual Studio 2010, getting 'The specified module could not be found (exception from Hresult: 0x800700E)' error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I am trying to create a database and its tables using the Visual Studio 2010 Sp1 itself from server explorer section.

I could successfully create the database but when I go for the tables I get the error:

> The specified module could not be found (exception from Hresult: 0x800700E)

I have SQL Server 2012 Enterprise installed on the system as well, and I'm trying to create the database inside visual studio using .\sqlexpress .

For the record: I had Visual Studio 2012 installed but removed it since I couldn't stand it. Does this have any relation to this problem?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I just wanted to chime in and say this fixed my problem as well. I'm using VS C# Express 2010 with an .accdb (new Access DB file) held within a remote location on a mapped server drive. I WAS using VS C# Express 2012, but scrapped it when M$ changed everything. Setting up the connection in DB explorer was easy enough, but when I went to query the table(s) via right-click -> retrieve data, I received the exact error as OP. All I did to fix was delete the .DLL from the above directory, fix the install (Control Panel -> programs -> repair Microsoft VS Express 2010 -> download files automatically)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK i solved the problem . 
It was caused by the former installation of Visual Studio 2012 and then its un-installations.
Visual Studio 2012 changes the `dsref80.dll` located at :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\

overwriting the older version.
When it is uninstalled the dll remains though and since its version is newer and there is no more the version 10 , Visual studio 2010 generates an error.
to resolve this problem all you need to do is to get the version 10 dll and place it in the mentioned path( a repair or re-installation would do the trick).
here is the dll on my system if anyone needs it .
[Here is the source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc/)

[dsref80.dll](http://sdrv.ms/UlBOr4)

Comment: Thanks for posting and also for the link to the signed dll. The source discussion link has a dll link, but that one is expired.

Answer (score 1):

Although, [Hossein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938244/hossein)'s answer is correct, I want to add that repairing Visual Studio 2010 didn't solve my problem. In addition to this, the file is at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Visual Database Tools
```

directory on my computer. I am using Windows 8. Just replace `dsref80.dll` at this directory with the file provided by Hossein.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue and wasted my time re-installing VS.

The solution is to simply replace the dsref80.dll file in the aforementioned directory, and still if it isn't working, restart your PC and copy is again from some a working system